# getting java.lang.IllegalStateException in android

Tags: java, android

I have action bar drop-down in my android application. When user click a item from the drop-down. I added a `AlertDialogBuilder` to get some user data from user, if user press ok it will save the data. When I run the code I got this exception.
[image: IMAGE_LOG]

this is the code I'm using

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final int i, long l) {


    final ArrayList<Host> hosts = HostFactory.getHosts(this.getApplicationContext());

    // get prompts.xml view
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.auto_discovery_prompt, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);

    // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

    final EditText txtDeviceName = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.txtdevicename_editTextDialogUserInput);
    final EditText txtUsername = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.txtusername_editTextDialogUserInput);
    final EditText txtPassword = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.txtpassword_editTextDialogUserInput);
    final EditText txtPort = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.txtport_editTextDialogUserInput);
    String mac=navSpinner.get(i).getMacaddress();

    txtDeviceName.setText(navSpinner.get(i).getTitle());
    txtPort.setText(navSpinner.get(i).getPort());
    for(SpinnerNavItem items:navSpinner)
    {
        if(items.getTitle().toString()!="Select your Device" )
        {

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int id) {
                                    // get user input and set it to result
                                    // edit text
                                    //result.setText(userInput.getText());

                                    String dd=txtPassword.getText().toString();


                                    Host savecurrent_selected_host =new Host();

                                    savecurrent_selected_host.name=txtDeviceName.getText().toString();
                                    savecurrent_selected_host.addr=navSpinner.get(i).getIPaddress().toString();

                                    try {
                                        savecurrent_selected_host.port = Integer.parseInt(txtPort.getText().toString());
                                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                        savecurrent_selected_host.port = Host.DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT;
                                    }

                                    savecurrent_selected_host.user=txtUsername.getText().toString();
                                    savecurrent_selected_host.pass=txtPassword.getText().toString();

                                    savecurrent_selected_host.esPort = Host.DEFAULT_EVENTSERVER_PORT;
                                    savecurrent_selected_host.timeout = Host.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
                                    savecurrent_selected_host.access_point="";
                                    if(!(navSpinner.isEmpty()&& navSpinner.get(i).getMacaddress().toString().isEmpty()))
                                        savecurrent_selected_host.mac_addr=navSpinner.get(i).getMacaddress().toString();
                                    else
                                        savecurrent_selected_host.mac_addr="";
                                    savecurrent_selected_host.wol_port = Host.DEFAULT_WOL_PORT;
                                    savecurrent_selected_host.wol_wait = Host.DEFAULT_WOL_WAIT;

                                    HostFactory.addHost(getApplicationContext(), savecurrent_selected_host);
                                    HostFactory.saveHost(getApplicationContext(),savecurrent_selected_host);

                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();

                                }
                            });

            // create alert dialog
            alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            if(!alertDialog.isShowing())
                alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?( application is braking when come to  `alertDialog.show()` )

Comment: What if you try the suggestion from the error message? Add `removeView` before `setView` on the Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have two issues with your code, and the first issue is causing the second.  The first issue is that you are displaying a new `alertDialog` for each item in `navSpinner`.  The following `if` statement

```
if(items.getTitle().toString()!="Select your Device" )
```

will always be `true` because you are doing reference comparison (`==`).  You want to use `.equals()`.  (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion) for a better explanation).

```
if(!items.getTitle().toString().equals("Select your Device" ))
```

Even this seems a little fishy, as you probably want to compare the loop item to the selected item, not some default string.  Anyways, as a result, you are creating a new `alertDialog` for each loop iteration

```
alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
```

`create()` returns a *new* dialog each time, so the following check

```
if(!alertDialog.isShowing())
```

is always `true`, as the *new* dialog which was created one line above has obviously not been shown yet.  The means the new `alertDialog` is always shown

```
alertDialog.show();
```

On first glance, you might expect this to result in multiple alert dialogs being shown, one for each item in the loop.  However, this will not be the case, as the second alert dialog - which will be created during the second iteration of the loop - will cause a `IllegalStateException`.  Why?  Because of this:

```
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
```

Although your second dialog truly is its own dialog, it shares the `promptsView` with the dialog that was created during the first loop iteration.  When `show()` is called, `promptsView` is given a parent.  This is OK when the first dialog is shown, because `promptsView` is a new view without a parent assigned.  However, when the second dialog is show - from the second loop iteration - the `show()` method attempts to give `promptsView` a parent, but this time it fails because it has already been given a parent from the first dialog `show()`.  And thus the error: *The specified child already has a parent*

In short, fix your loop so that only one dialog is displayed, and you should be good to go.